# Client socket closes after one loop

Tags: java, serversocket

I am working on a screensharing application in java but it doesn't work

So basically i am trying to send Screenshots through sockets but the client socket closes after it sends one screenshot

**Server**

```
   try {
        server = serverSocket.accept();
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream()));
        server.setKeepAlive(true);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
  while(true)
  { 

          BufferedImage screenshot = null;
        try {
            screenshot = ImageIO.read(server.getInputStream());
        } catch (NullPointerException | IOException e) {
            System.out.println("exception");
        }
        if(screenshot != null)
            panel.image = resize(screenshot, frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight());
        else
            System.out.println("null");
        frame.revalidate();
        panel.repaint();
  }
```

**Client**

```
String serverName = "127.0.0.1";
int port = 27005;

client = new Socket(serverName, port);
client.setKeepAlive(true);
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());

while(client.isConnected())
{

        Robot bot = new Robot();
        bimg = bot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
        ImageIO.write((RenderedImage)bimg, "jpg", out);
        out.flush();
}
```

Comment: `catch (NullPointerException`?? Your code should *never* have this

Comment: You appear to be repeatedly trying to get the input stream from the server in the while loop, and that doesn't look right. Instead, extract the InputStream and continue using it until done with it. Also your code goes against Swing threading rules.

Comment: The client socket does *not* close. However `ImageIO.read()` may be closing the *server* socket. Please clarify your actual symptoms.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels That's not correct. You can fetch a socket input steam as many times as you like. And  you can't tell what thread the client code is running on from this sample.

Comment: @EJP: I'll have to bow to your knowledge on the InputStream, though he has some side effects in that I'll bet he's not closing his streams when done. As for threading, there are two possibilities here: the code is called on the Swing event thread, the EDT, or it's not. If the code is called on the Swing event thread, then it will cause obvious problems since the while true loop will block it rendering the GUI useless, but even if called off of the EDT, it makes at least one mutational call on a Swing component, risking intermittent Swing threading errors.